# Indesign Javascript to convert dates

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am looking for an Adobe Indesign script to convert date formats.

**Example** 25/12/2022 to 25 December 2022

I found script which does exactly this but it is using the American date format mm/DD/yyyy and I need it use the UK date format dd/MM/yyyy

The original script came from this Adobe Community forum and was created by Oleh.melnyk

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/find-and-replace-date-format-indesign-cs6/m-p/13347884#M502699

Looking for someone to help update/convert the script to the UK Date format dd/MM/yyyy

```
//DESCRIPTION: Convert date format - finds 09/05/1936 and replac eit with 05 September 1936
#target indesign;

/*
    by Oleh Melnyk at 5 April 2017
    requested at https://forums.adobe.com/message/9436296#9436296
*/

//> START OF doUndoWraper
if (parseFloat(app.version) < 6) // "app.version < 6" if it's running under an earlier version than CS4, as earlier versions don't support "Undo" in scripts
    doUndoWrapper();
else
    app.doScript(doUndoWrapper, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "Change Date Format");
//< END OF doUndoWraper

function doUndoWrapper(){
    function toUnique(a, b, c) { //array,placeholder,placeholder
        b = a.length;
        while (c = --b)
            while (c--) a[b] !== a[c] || a.splice(c, 1);
        return a // not needed ;)
    }
    
   function convertDateFormat(date){
        var objDate = new Date(date);
        var monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        return  ("0" + objDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + monthName[objDate.getMonth()] + " " + objDate.getFullYear();
    }

    app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing; // clear settings

    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = false; // search in Locked Layers
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = false; // search in Locked Stories
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeHiddenLayers = false; // search in HiddenLayers
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeMasterPages = false; // search in Master Pages
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeFootnotes = true; // search in Footnotes

    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "\\d{2}\/\\d{2}\/\\d{4}";

    var whereToSearch = app.activeDocument; // default - search in entire document
    var foundPrep = whereToSearch.findGrep();
    
    var foundElements = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < foundPrep.length; x++){
         foundElements.push(foundPrep[x].contents); 
    }

    var foundUnique = toUnique(foundElements);

    for(var i = 0; i < foundUnique.length; i++){                
        var option = foundUnique[i];                
        app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = option;           
        app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = convertDateFormat(option);        
        whereToSearch.changeGrep();        
        app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing; // clear find what and change to field        
    } 
}
```

I have installed this script and used it but need it converted to use the UK Date format dd/MM/yyyy

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated script for **dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy** can be found on

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/find-and-replace-date-format-indesign-cs6/td-p/13200572

and below.

```
//DESCRIPTION: Convert date format - finds 09/05/1936 and replace it with 09 May 1936
#target indesign;

/*
    by Oleh Melnyk at 5 April 2017
    requested at https://forums.adobe.com/message/9436296#9436296
    
    Edited By :- Manan Joshi
    Edited the date format to dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy
*/

//> START OF doUndoWraper
if (parseFloat(app.version) < 6) // "app.version < 6" if it's running under an earlier version than CS4, as earlier versions don't support "Undo" in scripts
    doUndoWrapper();
else
    app.doScript(doUndoWrapper, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "Change Date Format");
//< END OF doUndoWraper

function doUndoWrapper(){
    function toUnique(a, b, c) { //array,placeholder,placeholder
        b = a.length;
        while (c = --b)
            while (c--) a[b] !== a[c] || a.splice(c, 1);
        return a // not needed ;)
    }
    
   function convertDateFormat(date){
    var t = date.split("/")
    date = t[1] + "/" + t[0] + "/" + t[2]
        var objDate = new Date(date);
        var monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        return  ("0" + objDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + monthName[objDate.getMonth()] + " " + objDate.getFullYear();
    }

    app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing; // clear settings

    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = false; // search in Locked Layers
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = false; // search in Locked Stories
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeHiddenLayers = false; // search in HiddenLayers
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeMasterPages = false; // search in Master Pages
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeFootnotes = true; // search in Footnotes

    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "\\d{1,2}\/\\d{1,2}\/\\d{4}";

    var whereToSearch = app.activeDocument; // default - search in entire document
    var foundPrep = whereToSearch.findGrep();
    
    var foundElements = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < foundPrep.length; x++){
         foundElements.push(foundPrep[x].contents); 
    }

    var foundUnique = toUnique(foundElements);

    for(var i = 0; i < foundUnique.length; i++){                
        var option = foundUnique[i];                
        app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = option;           
        app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = convertDateFormat(option);        
        whereToSearch.changeGrep();        
        app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing; // clear find what and change to field        
    } 
}
```

Comment: It would be good to add the core of the solution in your answer too. So if the link is down in the future, people will still have access to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of string manipulation and date formatting techniques.

```
const date = '25/12/2022';

// Parse the date string into a Date object
const dateObj = new Date(date);

// Get the month name from the Date object
const monthName = dateObj.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });

// Extract the day and year from the date string
const day = date.substring(0, 2);
const year = date.substring(6);

// Format the date using the month name, day, and year
const formattedDate = `${day} ${monthName} ${year}`;

console.log(formattedDate); // 25 December 2022
```

In this example, the date string is first parsed into a Date object using the Date constructor. Then use the toLocaleString() method to get the month name as a string. After that, the day and year are extracted from the date string using the substring() method. Finally, the date is formatted using the month name, day, and year.